# ¿Por qué my keypad arduino repite dígitos?

Tags: arduino

Tengo un código el cual según su funcionamiento es para el keypad pero lamentablemente cuando conecto mi keypad a los pines correspondientes my keypad repite dígitos, por ejemplo presiono 1 el serial sale 1 y presiono 2 y en el serial sale 2 otra vez y ya lo probé manual sin el keypad pin con pin con un jumper en el arduino y me sigue repitiendo dígitos.

```
#include <Keypad.h>
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'+','8','9'},
  {'#','0','*'},
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {8,7,6,5}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {4,3,2}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key != NO_KEY){
    Serial.println(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

deberías añadir un `delay()` entre cada lectura. El funcionamiento de un pulsador (como es el del keypad) consiste en dejar pasar la corriente cuando lo pulsas. Si lo dejas pulsado continua leyendo este valor y por eso te repite el valor varias veces. La solución más simple es añadir un `delay()`(500 milisegundos son correctos para poder pulsar y dejar ir el número seleccionado) entre las lecturas del keypad de la siguiente forma:

```
#include <Keypad.h>
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'+','8','9'},
  {'#','0','*'},
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {8,7,6,5}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {4,3,2}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if (key != NO_KEY){
    Serial.println(key);
  }
  delay(500); 
}
```